# PushViewController xib backgroundColor missing when navigation bar translucent is no

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xib

I have a `XIB` with a green background and a label. This `XIB` gets loaded in my `ViewController` and no frames are being set so it's being placed at the top. I'm pushing my `ViewController` onto the navigation stack and I can see my green `XIB` behind the navigation bar as expected because of the iOS7 translucency.

However, if I set the navigation bar translucent to **no**, the XIB gets pushed below the navigation bar and I can see the label, but the color is gone. Why is the backgroundColor all of a sudden ignored?